# Uso de dropdown de bootstrap para submenu

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

estoy usando una plantilla de bootstrap y el unico inconveniente que tengo es que aquí en la versión mobil para desplegar el submenu tengo que prescionar la flecha, pero quisiera que tambien al seleccionar la palabra "Servicios" se pueda desplegar,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código:

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a  style="color: #88868A" >Servicios</a>
    <div class="megamenu">
      <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-lg-6 column">
           <ul>
             <li class="linea linea1"><a href="{{ route('alquilerbombasvent.mostrar') }}">Alquiler de bombas y ventiladores</a></li>
             <li class="linea"><a href="{{ route('alquilerbombasvent.mostrar') }}">Alquiler de bombas y ventiladores</a></li>
             <li class="linea"><a href="{{ route('repbombasyvent.mostrar') }}">Reparacion de bombas y ventiladores</a></li>
             <li class="linea"><a class="" href="#">Venta de repuestos para bombas y ventiladores</a></li>
           </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
       </div>
     </a>
   </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que usar las siguientes clase para poder hacer eso, te lo dejo comentado para que se pueda entender mejor.

```
<!-- contenedor del menu -->
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <!-- boton que muestra el submenu -->
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
              Servicios
            </a>
            <!-- el sub menu -->
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Alquiler</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Reparacion</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ventas</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
```